# Answer with an image + button in dialogflow chat with fulfillment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm busy with learning more and more about dialogflow and the different possibilities that it has to offer but I'm stuck at the moment.

**What do I have now?**
Via my dialogflow agent it is possible at the moment to request the present travel advice from the Dutch gouverment to a specific country. So when an user is asking: 'give me the travel advice to Spain' the dialogflow will respond with the current travel advice from the gouverment.

The data is being imported from a Google Sheet. In this Google Sheet I fetch the realtime travel advice data from the gouverment webpage. The code I use to give the travel advice as feedback to the user is:

```
`function reisadviesHandler(agent) {
  const bestemming = agent.parameters.bestemming;
  return getSpreadsheetDataReisadvies().then(res => {
    res.data.map(land => {
      if(land.bestemming === bestemming)
      agent.add(`Momenteel staat het reisadvies voor ${bestemming} op ${land.kleurcode}. Het Ministerie van Buitenlandse Zaken zegt verder: ${land.melding}. Is er nog iets anders waar ik je mee kan helpen?`);
    });
  });
}`
```

Within the spreadsheet (where the data is coming from) I also added an url to the map (picture) of the travel advice ([example](https://opendata.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/binaries/content/gallery/nederlandwereldwijd/content-afbeeldingen/reisadviezen/europa/ierland/reisadvies_ierland_17-03-2020.png)) in column D called 'mapimage'. With `${land.mapimage}` I can pull the correct url to the right image for a specific country (the country is the dynamic value input from the user).

**What I want to do**
After the present answer:

> Momenteel staat het reisadvies voor ${bestemming} op
> ${land.kleurcode}. Het Ministerie van Buitenlandse Zaken zegt verder:
> ${land.melding}. Is er nog iets anders waar ik je mee kan helpen?

I want to ask if the user want to see the present travel advice map (image). If they respond / click on 'yes' the chatbot has to sent the picture(map) of the destination. Beside that I also want to add a button that makes it possible to forward the user to the correct gouverment webpage for more information regarding the travel advice.

At this moment sending the map (image) is the main issue, I don't know how to preform this within my present fulfillment code. Hope that anyone can help / explain this so I can continue building this chatbot happily :) Thx!

Comment: The answer depends a little bit on what clients/integrations you're using with Dialogflow. Are you targeting this for the Google Assistant? For a chatbot such as Facebook? For a web or an app integration?

Comment: Hi Prisoner, we will target Facebook M & Assistant :)

Comment: And web by the way but I think it is not possible in the dialogflow web message bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your use-case description, a [follow-up intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents#create) could be used, since it is a child of its associated parent intent and is commonly used for replies like ‘yes’, ’no’ or ‘cancel’. Also, you could use one of the [predefined follow-up intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/follow-up-intent-expressions) or create a custom one.

Additionally, since the answer is in function of the country value given by the user, the information of the selected country has to be persisted within the [active context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-overview), so it could be used within a follow-up intent. In order to persist data into the active context the function agent.setContext() can be used, by adding the data as parameters within your fulfillment code as follows.

```
function reisadviesHandler(agent) { 
   const bestemming = agent.parameters.bestemming; 
   return getSpreadsheetDataReisadvies().then(res => { 
      res.data.map(land => { 
          if(land.bestemming === bestemming) {
             agent.add(`Momenteel staat het reisadvies voor ${bestemming} op ${land.kleurcode}. Het Ministerie van Buitenlandse Zaken zegt verder: ${land.melding}. Is er nog iets anders waar ik je mee kan helpen?`);
             agent.setContext({ name: 'your context name here', lifespan: 1, parameters: { [param-name]: land.mapimage , [param-name]: land.website }}); // You can use your current context name or a new one is created with the name provided.
         }
      }); 
   }); 
}
```

By using the [Dialogflow simulator](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/console#simulator) you could see which are the contexts and active parameters during the intents interaction.

[image: Active context]

In order to access the previous persisted data within the follow-up intent configure the [intent parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters#where) pointing to the [context parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters#context) with that information.

[image: Intent parameters]

Finally, you can use the [Dialogflow Card response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages#card) to send images or interactive buttons, like the below example.

```
function yes(agent) {
    const mapimage = agent.parameters.mapimage;
    const webpage = agent.parameters.webpage;
    agent.add(new Card({
         title: `Title: this is a card title`,
         imageUrl: mapimage,
         text: `This is the body text of a card.`,
         buttonText: 'This is a button',
         buttonUrl: webpage
         })
      );
   }
```

Please note that the [fulfillment option](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#enable) within the follow-up intent has to be enabled and also within the fulfillment code, the intent has to be map to a function.

```
intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
```

Comment: Hi Mariana, thank you for your reply and help! Great that you are willing to help me with this matter. I tried to implement your suggestions but I'm facing a problem.

Once I add the line `agent.setContext()` the function **reisadviesHandler(agent)** is not working anymore (it is not returning the values land.kleurcode, bestemming and land.melding anymore.

I've changed your line to: `agent.setContext({ name: 'reisadvies-followup', lifespan: 1, parameters: { [land.mapimage]: mapimage , [land.website]: website }});`

Comment: Hi Sami, sorry I didn't clarify that the name parameters are without the brackets, and also the parameters format is : "paramete-name : parameter-value". Your line should look like this : `agent.setContext({ name: 'reisadvies-followup', lifespan: 1, parameters: { mapimage: land.mapimage , website: land.website }});`. Please notice, that the values **'mapimage'** and **'website'** have to exists within your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Mariana, thank you so much! It is working :). But it is very unstable, I think that has something to do with the GetSpreadsheet function... it is sometimes responding with no answer. But thats something else to find out. Thanks a million!

Comment: edit: I often get the message 'Not availible', when I'm not using the rich responds it is more stable. Is that possible?

Comment: Where are you testing the bot ?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply. I try this in the dialogflow test agent & Google Assistant. But I guess it has something to do with the fact that the GetSpreadsheet function is taking to long and that this is the reason that it gives 'Not available' as answer. If I put in the request for a second time it gives the right answer (may be because the file was already loaded once). Is this possible? And is it possible to script this function in a way that you give the code a bit longer to search for the right results?