# How to create Card response in Dialogflow fulfillment?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Dialogflow fulfillment index.js

```
function fallback(agent) {
    let user_input = agent.query;
    let google = 'https://www.google.co.th'
    agent.add('Your word is '+ user_input);
    agent.add(google);
  }
```

I want change the reply 'google link' to card or something for perfect chatbot

[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The card depends upon the client what you are using if you are using any custom web application client then you have to build a custom payload as per the client application.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow uses [rich responses](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages#card) to display visual elements to enhance user interactions, basically you have to init the Card object in the fulfillment index.js and include the button inside the Card

```js
function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(new Card({
         title: `Title: this is a card title`,
         text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
         buttonText: 'Click me',
         buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
       })
     );   
}
```

In addition to that, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64234039/how-to-show-rich-response-buttons-chips-using-dialogflow-fulfillment) there is a different way to perform the cards. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724904/answer-with-an-image-button-in-dialogflow-chat-with-fulfillment/63782484#63782484) there is more detailed information of how to add a button into a card.

Finally, there is an [unofficial repository](https://github.com/fabio-C/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) that includes multiple buttons in the Dialogflow response that is integrated and tested with Facebook messenger platform. You can see some [Dialogflow integrations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations) with multiple conversations platforms that already have buttons into a Card.